# How can I enable / disable location watch in leaflet?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

I would like to write a "position tracking" / "navigation" feature to my leaflet map. It means that the position is continuously displayed, but in "position tracking" function, the map always zoom and pan to the position marker. In "navigation" function the pan and zoom are not automatic.
And the app have a "Stop position reading" function.
When i click a button, a modal dialog shows with these 3 functions (input radio buttons can be selected).

I tried with "watch" value to set true and false. But the first option (tracking) is works, but no others.

```js
var gpsread = false;

gps_button.onclick = function() {
  var gps_value = document.querySelector('input[name = "gps"]:checked');

  if (gps_value != null) {
    switch (gps_value.value) {
      case "tracking":
        if ((gpsread = true)) { gpsread = false; map.stopLocate(); }
        if ((gpsread = true)) { alert("YES!"); } else { alert("NO!"); } // check, and only shows YES
        map.locate({ setView: true, maxZoom: 16, enableHighAccuracy: true, watch: true });
        gpsread = true;
        modal3.style.display = "none"; // close modal panel
        break;
      case "navigation":
        if ((gpsread = true)) { gpsread = false; map.stopLocate(); }
        if ((gpsread = true)) { alert("YES!"); } else { alert("NO!"); } // check
        map.locate({ setView: true, maxZoom: 16, enableHighAccuracy: true, watch: false });
        gpsread = true;
        modal3.style.display = "none"; // close modal panel
        break;
      case "stop":
        if ((gpsread = true)) {
          map.stopLocate();
          gpsread = false;
          map.removeLayer(current_position);
          map.removeLayer(current_accuracy);
        }
        modal3.style.display = "none"; // close modal panel
        break;
    }
  } else {
    if ((gpsread = true)) {
      gpsread = false;
      map.stopLocate();
      map.removeLayer(current_position);
      map.removeLayer(current_accuracy);
    }
    modal3.style.display = "none"; // close modal panel
  }
};
```

Comment: Be aware that you're using [assignment operators (`=`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators) inside your `if` conditions instead of [equality comparison operators (`==`, `===`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)!!

Comment: Thank you very much! It was a very amateurish mistake...